# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list, Thrown in for Loop

Tags: python

Every time I try to run this program, python throws the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

```
def symmetric_words(wlist):

alphabet = {"a":0,"b":1,"c":2,"d":3,"e":4,"f":5,"g":6,"h":7,"i":8,"j":9,"k":10,"l":11,"m":12,"n":13,"o":14,"p":15,"q":16,"r":17,"s":18,"t":19,"u":20,"v":21,"w":22,"x":23,"y":24,"z":25}
symmetric = []

for word in wlist:
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:
        symmetric.append(word)

for item in symmetric:
    for i in range(0,int(len(item)/2)-1):          
        if alphabet.get(item[i])!=(25-alphabet.get(item[len(item)-(i+1)])):
            symmetric.remove(item)

  return symmetric

print(symmetric_words(["neither", "a", "borrower", "nor", "a", "lender", "be"]))
```

The program is supposed to take a list of words as input and test if they're symmetrical (their first letter and last letter are the same distance away from their respective ends of the alphabet and so on), it works fine for the input list `["boy", "dog", "bevy", "bully"]`, bevy being symmetrical, but wont work for the input `["neither", "a", "borrower", "nor", "a", "lender", "be"]`, or several others I've tried, instead throwing the above error.
I've read up as much as I can and I believe its due to a value already having been deleted when python goes to again delete it from the list of symmetrical words, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

The program is meant to first check if the length of each word is even or odd, as no odd lengthed word could ever be symmetrical, then add the even lengthed words to the symmetric list. The symmetric list is then sent to the 2 nested for loops which are intended to remove any words not meeting the position requirements for a word to be symmetric, this is where the error occurs (line 10, the `symmetric.remove(item)` statement).
I'm sorry if this is a silly question, I really am very new to programming in general, thanks in advance or any and all help.

Comment: Never remove an item from a list while looping the same list. Bad things tend to happen.

Comment: If remove is the problem, why not change logic and create a new list of really symmetric words and add found symmetric. Just like you did with words and symmetric - instead of deleting odd elements from words list you've added even elements to new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that removing elements from a list, while iterating over them would be a bad idea. Instead you can use `all()` method to check if all the left side characters match the right one (according to your condition) and then if all of them are correct, append that to a new list. Code -

```
def symmetric_words(wlist):
    alphabet = {"a":0,"b":1,"c":2,"d":3,"e":4,"f":5,"g":6,"h":7,"i":8,"j":9,"k":10,"l":11,"m":12,"n":13,"o":14,"p":15,"q":16,"r":17,"s":18,"t":19,"u":20,"v":21,"w":22,"x":23,"y":24,"z":25}
    ret = []
    for item in wlist:
        if len(item) % 2 == 0:
            if all(alphabet.get(item[i])==(25-alphabet.get(item[len(item)-(i+1)])) for i in range(len(item)//2)):
                    ret.append(item)
    return ret
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def symmetric_words(wlist):
...     alphabet = {"a":0,"b":1,"c":2,"d":3,"e":4,"f":5,"g":6,"h":7,"i":8,"j":9,"k":10,"l":11,"m":12,"n":13,"o":14,"p":15,"q":16,"r":17,"s":18,"t":19,"u":20,"v":21,"w":22,"x":23,"y":24,"z":25}
...     ret = []
...     for item in wlist:
...             if len(item) % 2 == 0:
...                     if all(alphabet.get(item[i])==(25-alphabet.get(item[len(item)-(i+1)])) for i in range(len(item)//2)):
...                                     ret.append(item)
...     return ret
...
>>> print(symmetric_words(["boy", "dog", "bevy", "bully"]))
['bevy']
>>> print(symmetric_words(["neither", "a", "borrower", "nor", "a", "lender", "be"]))
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this bit:

```
for i in range(0,int(len(item)/2)-1):          
    if alphabet.get(item[i])!=(25-alphabet.get(item[len(item)-(i+1)])):
        symmetric.remove(item)
```

you are detecting that the string is not symmetrical and removing it from your symmetric list, but then carrying on through the loop and continuing to check it, so it will try and remove the same string over and over again. Try breaking out of your inner loop after you remove the string.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem; but creating a new list wiht a list comprehension or a filter is probably still better than removing elements while looping the list...